# Print ARGC in NASM without printf

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

Any good NASM/Intel Assembly programmers out there? If so, I have a question for you!

Every tutorial I can find online, shows the usage of "printf" for printing the actual value of ARGC to the screen (fd:/dev/stdout). Is it not possible to simply print it with sys_write() for example:

```
SEGMENT .data ; nothing here

SEGMENT .text ; sauce
        global _start
        _start:
                pop ECX ; get ARGC value
                mov EAX, 4 ; sys_write()
                        mov EBX, 1 ; /dev/stdout
                        mov EDX, 1 ; a single byte
                int 0x80
                mov EAX, 1 ; sys_exit()
                        mov EBX, 0 ; return 0
                int 0x80
SEGMENT .bss ; nothing here
```

When I run this, I get no output at all. I have tried copying ESP into EBP and tried using byte[EBP+4], (i was told the brackets de-reference the memory address).

I can confirm that the value when compared to a constant, works. For instance, 
this code works:

```
pop ebp ; put the first argument on the stack
mov ebp, esp ; make a copy 
cmp byte[ebp+4],0x5 ; does it equal 5?
je _good ; goto _good, &good, good()
jne _bad ; goto _bad, &bad, bad()
```

When we "pop" the stack, we technically should get the full number of arguments, no? Oh, btw, I compile with:

```
nasm -f elf test.asm -o test.o
ld -o test test.o
```

not sure if that is relevant. Let me know if i need to provide more information, or format my code for readability.

Comment: `sys_write` takes a pointer to a character string (and the number of characters in the array). You need to convert your number _argc_ to a string and then pass a pointer to that into `sys_write` system call.

Comment: It's often useful to write something in C and look at the compiler output.  Esp. while you're learning, it'll catch mistakes like this (value vs. pointer needed for `write(2)`).  Also, using `pop` to get your args is weird.  It works in `_start`, but in any other context the bottom of the stack will hold your return address.  Also, `pop ebp` / `mov ebp, esp` is weird.  Why not just `add esp, 4` if you're going to overwrite ebp in the next instruction anyway?  If you haven't seen it, check out http://agner.org/optimize/ and other links on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: @kp101st: You shouldn't put "SOLVED" in the title. If there's an answer that solves your problem, mark it as accepted (and upvote if you want to).

Comment: @Michael Thank you! I am a newbie! :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least 2 problems.

1. You need to pass a pointer to the thing you want to print.
2. You probably want to convert to text.

Something like this should work:

```
SEGMENT .text ; sauce
        global _start
        _start:
                mov ecx, esp        ; pointer to ARGC on stack
                add byte [esp], '0' ; convert to text assuming single digit
                mov EAX, 4 ; sys_write()
                mov EBX, 1 ; /dev/stdout
                mov EDX, 1 ; a single byte
                int 0x80
                mov EAX, 1 ; sys_exit()
                mov EBX, 0 ; return 0
                int 0x80
```

Comment: Shouldn't `pointer to ARGV on stack` be `pointer to ARGC on stack`?

Comment: @Jester Thank you! That is what was wrong, definitely. and the new lines to get ARGV[0] work perfectly in my system! Thank you!!

Comment: @Michael Thanks! good catch, I'll update the comment in my original post :)

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's comments where very helpful! I am honored that you all pitched in and helped! I have used @Jester's code,

```
SEGMENT .text ; sauce
        global _start
        _start:
                mov ecx, esp        ; pointer to ARGC on stack
                add byte [esp], '0' ; convert to text assuming single digit
                mov EAX, 4 ; sys_write()
                mov EBX, 1 ; /dev/stdout
                mov EDX, 1 ; a single byte
                int 0x80
                mov EAX, 1 ; sys_exit()
                mov EBX, 0 ; return 0
                int 0x80
```

Which works perfectly when compiled, linked and loaded. The sys_write() function requires a pointer, such like in the common "Hello World" example, the symbol "msg" is a pointer as seen in the code below.

```
SECTION .data ; initialized data
    msg: db "Hello World!",0xa
SECTION .text ; workflow
    global _start
    _start:
        mov EAX, 4
        mov EBX, 1
        mov ECX, msg ; a pointer!
```

So first, we move the **stack pointer** into the counter register, **ECX**, with the code,

```
mov ecx, esp ; ecx now contains a pointer!
```

and then convert it to a string by **adding a '0' char to the value pointed to** by ESP (which is ARGC), by **de-referencing** it with square brackets, as [ESP] like so,

```
add byte[esp], '0' ; update the value stored at "esp"
```

Again, thank you all for the great help! <3

Comment: Since Jester's answer solved your issue you should accept his answer. Please see this about [how/why you should accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was just reading that and I will from now on. Thank you for the help! I don't really like having questions that stump me hard enough to actually make posts, interact and ask questions and such, because I am a busy body. But, I actually can't wait to have another one, just so I can learn from you all! I love this site! :)